# Python and regex: create a template

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to find a lot of substrings in string but It takes a lot of time, so I need to combine it in pattern:

I should find string

```
003.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
1click.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
3dnews.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
```

where `%` - is an any symbols
and `[KEYWORD]` - can be ['sony%xperia', 'iphone', 'samsung%galaxy', 'lenovo_a706']

I try to do a search with

```
keywords = ['sony%xperia', 'iphone', 'samsung%galaxy', 'lenovo_a706']
for i, key in enumerate(keywords):
    coding['keyword_url'] = coding.url.apply(lambda x: x.replace('[KEYWORD]', key).replace('%', '[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.\?!@#$%^&*+=]+') if '[KEYWORD]' in x else x.replace('%', '[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.\?!@#$%^&*+=]+'))
    for (domain, keyword_url) in zip(coding.domain.values.tolist(), coding.keyword_url.values.tolist()):
        df.loc[df.event_address.str.contains(keyword_url), 'domain'] = domain
```

Where `df` contains only `event_address` (urls)

coding

```
domain  url
003.ru  003.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
1CLICK  1click.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
33033.ru    33033.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
3D NEWS 3dnews.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
96telefonov.ru  96telefonov.ru/%[KEYWORD]%
```

How can I improve my pattern to do it faster?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should consider using [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Look at the re.compile function for your patterns and then you can match them.